# Create dynamically a bootstrap 3.0.0 Slider

Tags: html, twitter-bootstrap, slider, carousel

i am trying to create a dynamic Slider to add all the employees birthday of the month, so i have a slider that has 3 images, and it scrolls images 3 by 3, but i need to do this dynamically i have my ajax, that conects to the data base and brings all the employee and i have a folder with the images, my ajax brings the user ID, name, last name and date and the images.
the code i have is like this:

```
<div class="container">
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-md-3">
                    <h3>BIRTHDAY OF THE MONTH</h3>
                    <p>All employees birthdays in January</p>
                    <div class="btn-group">
                        <a class="btn btn-danger" href="#scroller" data-slide="prev"><i class="icon-angle-left"></i></a>
                        <a class="btn btn-danger" href="#scroller" data-slide="next"><i class="icon-angle-right"></i></a>
                    </div>
                    <p class="gap"></p>
                </div>
                <div class="col-md-9">
                    <div id="scroller" class="carousel slide">
                        <div class="carousel-inner">
                            <div class="item active">
                                <div class="row">
                                    <div class="col-xs-4">
                                        <div class="portfolio-item">
                                            <div class="item-inner">
                                                <img class="img-responsive" src="images/employee/ID.jpg" alt="">
                                                <h5>
                                                    NAME LAST NAME and DATE
                                                </h5>
                                            </div>
                                        </div>
                                    </div>                            
                                    <div class="col-xs-4">
                                        <div class="portfolio-item">
                                            <div class="item-inner">
                                                <img class="img-responsive" src="images/employee/ID.jpg" alt="">
                                                <h5>
                                                    NAME LAST NAME and DATE
                                                </h5>
                                            </div>
                                        </div>
                                    </div>                            
                                    <div class="col-xs-4">
                                        <div class="portfolio-item">
                                            <div class="item-inner">
                                                <img class="img-responsive" src="images/employee/ID.jpg" alt="">
                                                <h5>
                                                    NAME LAST NAME and DATE
                                                </h5>
                                            </div>
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                </div><!--/.row-->
                            </div><!--/.item-->
                            <div class="item">
                                <div class="row">
                                    <div class="col-xs-4">
                                        <div class="portfolio-item">
                                            <div class="item-inner">
                                                <img class="img-responsive" src="images/employee/ID.jpg" alt="">
                                                <h5>
                                                    NAME LAST NAME and DATE
                                                </h5>
                                            </div>
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="col-xs-4">
                                        <div class="portfolio-item">
                                            <div class="item-inner">
                                                <img class="img-responsive" src="images/employee/ID.jpg" alt="">
                                                <h5>
                                                    NAME LAST NAME and DATE
                                                </h5>
                                            </div>
                                        </div>
                                    </div>                            
                                    <div class="col-xs-4">
                                        <div class="portfolio-item">
                                            <div class="item-inner">
                                                <img class="img-responsive" src="images/employee/ID.jpg" alt="">
                                                <h5>
                                                    NAME LAST NAME and DATE
                                                </h5>
                                            </div>
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </div><!--/.item-->
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div><!--/.row-->
        </div>
```

Hope you could help me, all i need to do is create first the active item, and then if i have more than 3 images create another div with the class item and inside that dive another div with the class row and then add the images.

Comment: Which server side language are u using? Mvc,php,web forms, ruby? Or do you want to do it just with jquery?

Comment: I am Using PHP, i do a Ajax with Jquery to get all the info, and then i would like to dinamcly create that slider with the images that i get